# proving that a group is a subfield of ℝ

Tags: field-theory

can someone help me with this question:

$\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]: = ⟨a + b\sqrt2 \mid a,b ∈ ℚ ⟩$

prove that $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ with the addition and multiplication of ℝ, and that it is a field.

I don't know how to write the accurate symbols, so if you're not sure of something please let me know.

i know that there's a quick way to show that Q[√2] is a sub field but i don't understand how to do it. 
(English is not my first language so please, try to explain your logic a bit slower than usual.. much appreciated!)

thank you

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i checked it. i don't understand how what they wrote prove that it is a field. can you please explain?

Comment: Can’t you just show directly that it satisfies the field axioms?

Comment: @MPW i could, but the teacher talked about a "shortcut" very briefly so i was hoping someone would know it here.

Comment: The linked answer says to use the fact that $(x^2−2)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Q[x]$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner we just started learning this subject. i still don't know what that means

Comment: $(x^2-2) $ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Q[x]$, meaning there's no ideal properly containing $(x^2-2)$ and properly contained in $\mathbb Q[x]$, and there's a theorem that the quotient ring of a maximal ideal in a commutative ring with unity is a field

Comment: To prove a set is a subfield, it suffices to show that it contains 1, and that it is closed for addition, multiplication, and both types of inverses. Is that perhaps what is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A subfield of a field L is a subset K of L that is a field with respect to the field operations inherited from L. Equivalently, a subfield is a subset that contains 1, and is closed under the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and taking the inverse of a nonzero element of L.

$\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ contains $1$. We can trivially show that it is closed for addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

That leaves whether it contains the multiplicative inverses of nonzero elements.
For that we have:
$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt 2}=\frac{a-b\sqrt 2}{(a+b\sqrt 2)(a-b\sqrt2)}=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2} + \frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt 2$$
which is an element of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$.

QED

Comment: note:  $a^2-2b^2$ is non-zero if $a+b\sqrt2$ is

Comment: thanks, was looking for this exact answer. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is is a short conceptual  proof, which is not in the link given above:

As $\sqrt 2$ is a root of a polynomial in $\mathbf Q[X]$, the ring  $\mathbf Q\bigl[\sqrt 2\,\bigr]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbf Q$-vector space, with basis $\{1,\sqrt 2\}$.

Now, multiplication by a nonzero element $x$  in this ring is a  linear map, and it is *injective* since it is  a subring of $\mathbf R$, hence an integral domain. And  for an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space, injective implies surjective, hence $1$ is attained, i.e. there exists $y\in \mathbf Q\bigl[\sqrt 2\,\bigr]$ such that $xy=1$.